# How to delete a repository on Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

I would like to delete a repository on Artifactory.

I looked up and found out [an API for deleting repository is provided](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeleteRepository); however, our installed product is not Pro, and we can't use the API.

Is there any other way to delete a repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete a repository using the UI:

- Go to Admin > Repositories > Local / Remote / Virtual
- Hover over the repository you wish to delete
- Click the delete button which is shown on the right side of the grid
- Confirm that you are willing to delete

[image]